# Android File.listFiles() not working for some directories

Tags: android, file, permissions

I have read/write/management permissions added to my manifest.  Permissions are granted for my app.  Most directories can be accessed just fine, but one is not.

```
    File test = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/aDirectory");

    boolean writable = test.canWrite();
    boolean readable = test.canRead();
```

writable and readable returns false so test.listFiles() returns null.  Yet, the same directory can be accessed from another activity.  Help please.

Comment: So the title of your post should be: File.listFiles() not working for some activities. Hard to believe.

Comment: Using an Android 11+ device?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an Android 11+ device.

Comment: I do not believe that the result of listFiles() would depend on the used activity. So you might elaborate on that. Further its quite normal on Android 11+ devices that your app sees less files in directories as for instance the default Files app.